# Why do I get a different result when I git clone from ssh and http?

Tags: git, http, ssh

I got a bare repository served directly using Apache:

```
http://gordon.re/files/t++.git/
```

If I clone it using SSH:

```
git clone ssh://user/home/user/www/files/t++.git
```

I got the last version (from today).

If I clone it using using HTTP:

```
 git clone https://gordon.re/files/t++.git
```

I got a version from the 6th of june.

Why, and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it help to do `git update-server-info` inside the repository on the server? The dumb HTTP transport method needs some extra files in order to work, and those have to be kept up-to-date: one of the example hooks does this (post-update, I think).